# WPF button to update a textbox in xaml with validator

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

How can I get a button to reset text in a textbox to a known value? In my example the validation rule is triggered so I can't use the button command to update the property, which is good because I don't want the property set if it's not valid.  I just want the button to basically reset the value in xaml without involving the property.  How would I do that?

```
   <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="20" Width="105" Name="Elevation"
             Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate1}" Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}">
        <TextBox.Text >
            <Binding Path="Elevation" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <rules:NotEmptyValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"/>
                    <rules:DoubleValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
 <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="9" Height="20" Command="{Binding ClickResetCommand}" CommandParameter="Elevation" >R</Button>
```

Still looking for a XAML solution but for now I've change the button to use OnClick and in the code behind using the following...

```
  case "Elevation":
   Elevation.Text = "50";
   Validation.ClearInvalid(Elevation.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
   Elevation.Focus();
  break;
```

Comment: I'm guessing you don't want to add a little code behind to process the button click?

Comment: If I have to, but thought there might be an easy XAML solution but I couldn't find one.